# Error in Magento join

Tags: magento, join, grid, admin

I have this code in my grid. I'm trying to retrive some fields from order and order_address. I'm getting this sQL query generated for my join:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`region`, `main_table`.`city`, `order`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_address` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `` AS `order` ON order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id WHERE (address_type = 'shipping') AND (region = 'California') GROUP BY `city`
```

I can see this in the query: `LEFT JOIN '' AS 'order'`. That's not correct. Here is the code where the query is generated. Any help is welcome.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('region')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('city')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('address_type', 'shipping')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('region', 'California');

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('order' => $this->getTable('sales/order')),//The problem is here!
        'order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id',
        array('order.*'))
        ->group('city');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it using the plain table names, like this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('order' => 'sales_flat_order'),
        'order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id',
        array('order.*'))
        ->group('city');
```

Not happy with this, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

in a class extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid`, Magento's core use underscores for getting the table name:

```
$coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('region')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('city')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('address_type', 'shipping')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('region', 'California');

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')),
    'order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id',
    array('order.*'))
    ->group('city');
```